# Can I build this typescript object dynamically?

Tags: angular, typescript, object

Here is the object I would like to be dynamic. How can I do this? 
I want to add more fields onto this when needed.

```
request = {
      header:{
        consumingAppId:"USER",
        userTypeCd : "S",
        instanceId : "QA",
      },
      userInfo:{
         firstName: "John",
         lastName: "Doe"
      }
}
```

Comment: Do you have some constraints on what the properties should be, or do you want it to accept any key with any value?

Comment: Yea I would know what the possible properties would be. Also values will come from different gets from the database. So it needed to be dynamic for that. @NicholasTower

Comment: `Yea I would know what the possible properties would be.` Then can you create an `interface` with those properties, marking them as optional where appropriate?

Comment: Would you be able to provide a short example of how to do this? I will accept answer as correct then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the possible properties ahead of time, you can create an interface with them. Any properties which are optional you can use `?`.

```
interface MyRequest {
  header: {
    consumingAppId: string,
    userTypeCd: string,
    instanceId: string,
  },
  userInfo: {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    nickName?: string, // example of an optional property on the userInfo object
  },
  metadata?: { // this entire metadata object can be left off
    id: number; // but if metadata exists, it must have an id
    price?: number;
  }
}

const request: MyRequest = {
  header: {
    consumingAppId: "USER",
    userTypeCd : "S",
    instanceId : "QA",
  },
  userInfo: {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe"
  }
}

request.userInfo.nickName = 'scar face'; // legal
request.userInfo.favoriteColor = 'blue'; // illegal, because there's no favoriteColor in the type
```

For more information see [documentation on optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties).